# How to set default browser window coordinates view?

Tags: html, css, browser

I have an HTML page with lots of real estate, but I want the window to default to a certain section of the page (i.e., I wanna specify the XY coordinates). How can I do this?

I tried searching around on SO and looking up certain tags on W3, but I don't seem to see any way to do this. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you saying that when the page is loaded you want it to automatically be scrolled down to a specific section of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with css.

```
.box
{
  position:absolute;
  top:123px;
  left:123px;
  display:block;
}

<div class="box">
  hi there
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you know the id of the element (say div or span). All you will have to do is apply jQuery on this element in this fashion

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#elementName').offset().top - 5
}, 'slow');
```

You can take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/QGL6A/